# Using sendmail as SMTP server in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sendmail

I have a Play Framework application that sends emails using SMTP server. Now I have a GMail account handling these emails but I do have sendmail installed and want to use it instead.

I have the following configuration in application.conf:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=myaddress@gmail.com
mail.smtp.pass=password
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

How can I change these lines so that installed sendmail application is used instead? It's working and I can send emails by "sendmail -v acc@dom.com < mail.txt" commands.

**UPDATE**

This should look like this:

```
mail.smtp.host=localhost
mail.smtp.from=My Account
```

It was failing because mail.smtp.from was not defined. "mail.debug=true" helped me to find that out. Thanks, *Codemwnci*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
mail.smtp.host=localhost
# comment old gmail settings
#mail.smtp.user=myaddress@gmail.com
#mail.smtp.pass=password
#mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

See here for all the config properties - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#mail

Comment: Not working, I've tried that at the very beginning. How can I debug what's going on and why this is not working?

Comment: I see that Play tries to send an email, though no success and no exception. Sendmail logs are empty

Comment: I could not find the Mail and SimpleMail in Play 2.0. Any idea how to accomplish this in play2.0?

Comment: this has to be done yourself in Play2...i believe a plugin now exists...I'll create a new question for you

Comment: added a new question for you here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492858/sending-emails-in-playframework-2-0/10492895#10492895