# Sending Emails in Playframework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Playframework 2.0, it does not appear to be as simple to send emails (see comments on [Using sendmail as SMTP server in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890616/using-sendmail-as-smtp-server-in-play-framework/8890858#comment13560881_8890858)) as it did in Play 1.x. There is no out of the box mailer functionality... so, how do I send emails?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Playframework 2.x requires a plugin for Mail to work. It was not added to the core because developers felt it was trivial to get Email working, so decided it was better to create a plugin. However, the quick flurry of messages on google groups suggested they got it wrong...people expected the same functionality as Play 1.x.

As you expect from the community though, a plugin was quickly built. See https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer.

There will be more plugins to look out for as well, but this is the typesafe supported one by a core developer, so I expect it to be the best maintained.

Comment: This list of plugins for 2.0 has been handy--note that it is supposed to be temporary: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules

Comment: @Codemwnci: I'm looking through this module for attachment support but it seems to be either hiding or non-existent. Tips?

Comment: Path is wrong in readme - try `"com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-mailer_2.9.1" % "2.0.4"`. notice `_2.9.1`.

Comment: If you're using Play! 2.1, use this dependency:
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0"

Comment: @LeventeHolló what's the dependency for 2.2.6? Thank you

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is that Play needs a plugin to send e-mails. This is false. You can easily adapt any JVM mailing library for your Play app. Here's an example using Apache Commons Email, adapted for simplicity from [here](https://gist.github.com/mariussoutier/3436111) and our own production code.

```
import org.apache.commons.mail._
import scala.util.Try

private val emailHost = Play.configuration.getString("email.host").get

/**
 *  Sends an email
 *  @return Whether sending the email was a success
 */
def sendMail(from: (String, String), // (email -> name)
             to: Seq[String],
             cc: Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
             bcc: Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
             subject: String,
             message: String,
             richMessage: Option[String] = None,
             attachment: Option[java.io.File] = None) = {

  val commonsMail: Email = if(mail.attachment.isDefined) {
      val attachment = new EmailAttachment()
      attachment.setPath(mail.attachment.get.getAbsolutePath)
      attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT)
      attachment.setName("screenshot.png")
      new MultiPartEmail().attach(attachment).setMsg(mail.message)
    } else if(mail.richMessage.isDefined) {
      new HtmlEmail().setHtmlMsg(mail.richMessage.get).setTextMsg(mail.message)
    } else {
      new SimpleEmail().setMsg(mail.message)
    }
  }

  commonsMail.setHostName(emailHost)

  to.foreach(commonsMail.addTo(_))
  cc.foreach(commonsMail.addCc(_))
  bcc.foreach(commonsMail.addBcc(_))

  val preparedMail = commonsMail.
    setFrom(mail.from._2, mail.from._1).
    setSubject(mail.subject)

  // Send the email and check for exceptions
  Try(preparedMail.send).isSuccess
}

def sendMailAsync(...) = Future(sendMail(...))
```

Given that e-mail sending is so trivially accomplished in Play, I'm surprised plugins are recommended at all. Depending on a plugin can hurt you if you want to upgrade Play versions, and I don't feel something that takes 30 LoC to accomplish yourself is worth it. Our code has worked unmodified upgrading from Play 2.0 to 2.1 to 2.2.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I quickly hacked plugin with support for attachments, because so far the one mentioned @Codemwnci doesn't have it. [You can check it out](https://github.com/mcveat/mail-plugin).